# Regex add space to camelCase - but not if a trailing upperCase letter exists

Tags: regex

So i've found this - working code sample

`\\B[A-Z])", " $1"`

However I don't want it to space out things like "AccountUserID" to "Account User I D" - so basically no spacing if a trailing uppercase letter exists

Can anyone show me a better approachable way - possibly using capturing groups and a negative digit identifier.

Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Try this with `ABC`](https://regex101.com/r/mS0vT5/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If lookbehind is supported then you can use:

```
(?<![A-Z])\B(?=[A-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO8jL5/2)

And replace it by just `" "`

Comment: this solution will add an extra needless space to `User_ID`

Comment: without lookaheads `str.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern :

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

and replace with a white space
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO8jL5/3)

Comment: Still, the most efficient is `([a-z])([A-Z])` -> `$1$2` replacement.